# How to display "add to wallet button" in flutter

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, wallet

I want to display add to wallet button in Flutter. I have written some native codes, channel and where to display this button. Now the button is visible. But can not control it. I can not  put it in the exact place. For example, I want to put a button after the texts. But the button still stays on the appbar and doesn't move.

My AppDelegate file is like this :

```
import PassKit

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
            let controller: FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
            let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "your_wallet_channel", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
            channel.setMethodCallHandler { (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) in
                if call.method == "showAddToWalletButton" {
                    WalletMethods.showAddToWalletButton()
                } else {
                    result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                }
            }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}


import PassKit

class WalletMethods {
    static func showAddToWalletButton() {
        let passButton = PKAddPassButton(addPassButtonStyle: .black)

        passButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 44)

        passButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addToWalletButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        let controller = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        controller?.view.addSubview(passButton)
    }

    @objc private func addToWalletButtonTapped() {
        
    }
}
```

Also I have created channel for connection between native code.

```
class WalletChannel {
  static const MethodChannel _channel = MethodChannel('your_wallet_channel');

  static Future<void> showAddToWalletButton() async {
    await _channel.invokeMethod('showAddToWalletButton');
  }
}
```

And finally my screen is like this

```
class _WalletScreenState extends State<WalletScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      showAddToWalletButton();
    });
  }

  void showAddToWalletButton() {
    WalletChannel.showAddToWalletButton();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Wallet Screen')),
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text('Welcome to Your Wallet'),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Text('This is your digital wallet.'),
          SizedBox(height: 20),
          Text('Manage your cards and passes.'),
          SizedBox(height: 40),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It stays where you have positioned it: `passButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 44)`. Change the `x` and `y` offsets to your desired position on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library you are using, and to be honest is the first time I have seen someone using Flutter like this.

There might be different reasons for what you are experiencing.
I notice a few things out of the code.

There is no reference in your build to where the button should be positioned, meaning the library creates the button and places it on the view in some default place, that as you say, is the header.
When you call the button on the init, it immediately places it on the view.

Look up the library reference, check how can you get the reference for the button, and place it on the build tree.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have already set up communication between Flutter and native iOS code using pipe methods. However, you are having trouble positioning the "Add to Wallet" button where you want it in your Flutter interface. Here are some things to check to fix this problem:

1. **Button Positioning:** Currently, you set the button position using

```
passButton.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 44)
```

. This places the button at coordinates (20, 20) in the global view. To position it under the texts, you will have to adjust these coordinates according to the layout of the texts in your `Column`.

2. **Layout Management:** Make sure you adjust the coordinates of the button according to the layout of the texts in your `Column`. For example, if you want the button to be placed after the texts, you can try using
   `passButton.frame.origin.y as the vertical starting point, adding the heights of the texts and blank spaces. This will give you the vertical position from which you can place your button.
3. **Adding the button to the correct widget:** You are currently adding the button directly to the root of the view

```
(`controller?.view.addSubview(passButton)`)
```

. This can cause layering and positioning issues. To place the button in the right place in your Flutter interface, you may need to add the button to a widget that will position it correctly relative to other elements.

4. **Updated Flutter UI:** Once you have added the button to the correct view, make sure the native view changes are correctly reflected in the Flutter UI. You may be able to force a UI update after adding the button using

```
setState(() {})
```

.

5. **Coordinate conversion:** Please keep in mind that coordinates in native iOS code and in the Flutter interface may differ due to view hierarchy and widget organization. You may need to convert coordinates between the two systems to position the button correctly.
6. **Test and tweak:** Experiment with different positioning and layout values to see how the button reacts. This might require iterative adjustments until you get the desired effect.